# PostgreSQL dblink password encrypted or not?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, postgresql-9.3, ssl, dblink

I have two PostgreSQL servers:

server 1: 192.168.0.1
server 2: 192.168.0.2

I want to connect to the database on server 2 from server 1. I do it like this:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('hostaddr=192.168.0.2 port=5432 dbname=mydb user=postgres password=mypasswd');
```

My question is that when I do such connect my password is send as plaintext or its somehow encrypted during the transmission to the server 2?

I use PostgreSQL 9.3 on Linuxx Mint 16 (server 1) and Xubuntu 13.10 (server 2).

Answer (score 4):

Basically, dblink uses a libpq-style connection info string.
Add **`sslmode=require`** to your connection string or a more restrictive setting to disallow unencrypted transfers. [More details in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html#LIBPQ-SSL-PROTECTION)

I would also advice *not* to have the password in your SQL statement *at all*. SQL statements may get logged. Or backups are stored in an insecure location ...
I use [the password file **`.pgpass`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) for dblink connections.